# Multi-Indexed data to nested list of objects

Tags: pandas

I have some data that looks like this...

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]],
    columns=[
        ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c'], 
        ['col1', 'col2', 'col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4']
    ]
)
#      a         b         c     
#   col1 col2 col1 col2 col3 col4
# 0    1    2    3    4    5    6
# 1    5    6    7    8    9   10
```

I want to have this formatted as...

```py
formatted_data
# [{'a': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2},
#   'b': {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4},
#   'c': {'col3': 5, 'col4': 6}},
#  {'a': {'col1': 5, 'col2': 6},
#   'b': {'col1': 7, 'col2': 8},
#   'c': {'col3': 9, 'col4': 10}}]
```

I have indeed achieved what I want, but the solution is either unreadable, poorly efficient, or <insert_random_negative_term>. And so I would like to know if there are some other ways of achieving this in a more readable manner. Preferably staying inside the `pandas` api. Efficiency is not important here, as the data is small, and the operation must be performed once.

```py
def get_multi_index_key(data, col_name):
    return data[col_name].to_dict("records")

def preformat_data(df, columns):
    multi_index_values = zip(*[get_multi_index_key(df, key) for key in columns])
    for row in multi_index_values:
        yield dict(
            zip(columns, row)
        )

formatted_data = preformat_data(df, ["a", "b", "c"])
next(formatted_data)
# {'a': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}, 'b': {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4}, 'c': {'col3': 5.0, 'col4': 6.0}}
```

The problem with the solutions that have been proposed is that the columns at `level=1` are all shared between the MultiIndexes, meaning that the result is...

```py
[{'a': {'col1': 1.0, 'col2': 2.0, 'col3': nan, 'col4': nan},
  'b': {'col1': 3.0, 'col2': 4.0, 'col3': nan, 'col4': nan},
  'c': {'col1': nan, 'col2': nan, 'col3': 5.0, 'col4': 6.0}},
 {'a': {'col1': 5.0, 'col2': 6.0, 'col3': nan, 'col4': nan},
  'b': {'col1': 7.0, 'col2': 8.0, 'col3': nan, 'col4': nan},
  'c': {'col1': nan, 'col2': nan, 'col3': 9.0, 'col4': 10.0}}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Pandas solution

```
s = df.stack(0)
s['r'] = s.to_dict('r')
s['r'].unstack().to_dict('r')
```

**General pandas solution corresponding to OP's update:**

```
s = df.melt(var_name=['l0', 'l1'], ignore_index=False)
s.groupby([s.index, 'l0']).apply(lambda s: dict(zip(s.l1, s.value))).unstack().to_dict('records')
```

---

```
[{'a': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2},
  'b': {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4},
  'c': {'col3': 5, 'col4': 6}},
 {'a': {'col1': 5, 'col2': 6},
  'b': {'col1': 7, 'col2': 8},
  'c': {'col3': 9, 'col4': 10}}]
```

Comment: I feel like my minimal example was too minimal and misleading. Do you think this is still doable with the new minimal example ?

Answer (score 2):

You may try with for loop with `to_dict`

```
out = [df.loc[[x]].stack().reset_index(level=0,drop=True).to_dict() for x in df.index]
Out[608]: 
[{'a': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}, 'b': {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4}},
 {'a': {'col1': 5, 'col2': 6}, 'b': {'col1': 7, 'col2': 8}}]
```

Comment: I feel like my minimal example was too minimal and misleading. Do you think this is still doable with the new minimal example ?

Answer (score 0):

This would work

```
def nest(d: dict) -> dict:
    result = {}
    for key, value in d.items():
        target = result
        for k in key[:-1]:  # traverse all keys but the last
            target = target.setdefault(k, {})
        target[key[-1]] = value
    return result

def df_to_nested_dict(df: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    d = df.to_dict(orient='index')
    return {k: nest(v) for k, v in d.items()}

result = df_to_nested_dict(df)
```

If you print `result`, you will get the desired output -

```
{
    0: {
        'a': {'col1': 1, 'col2': 2}, 
        'b': {'col1': 3, 'col2': 4}
    },
    1: {
        'a': {'col1': 5, 'col2': 6}, 
        'b': {'col1': 7, 'col2': 8}
    }
}
```